# hadoop DbDataReader.GetValue gets wrong timestamp

Tags: c#, hadoop, hive, hdfs, dbdatareader

i'm querying an hadoop cluster with **DbDataReader.GetValue** in c#.
the problem is that i'm getting a wrong value on timestamp.
The value in hdfs file (and when querying via hive) is 
***1997-03-21 01:00:00***
But with DbDataReader.GetValue i'm getting ***1997-03-21 00:00:00***
***1h*** offset.
Any idea what might the issue?
thanks!

Comment: It is a timezone issue.  The database is in a different timezone than your PC.

Comment: i don't think so...
i've just noticed that it's not happening to all dates.
for example 1997-02-21 00:00:00 stays as is.
might be that the timestamp being truncated?